# Add left side border color programmatically

Tags: android

This code adds a red border to a LinearLayout:

```
ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable();
sd.setShape(new RectShape());
sd.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
sd.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(1f);
sd.getPaint().setStyle(Style.STROKE);

linearLayout.setBackground(sd);
```

I need to add a red line to the left side of the Layout. How can I do it programmatically and without using any XML?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution:

```
        GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
        border.setStroke(1, color);
        border.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);

        Drawable[] layers = {border};

        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

        layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 1, -2, -2, -2);

        linearLayout.setBackground(layerDrawable);
```